# Even tho I turned on SSL in Nginx it does not work?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup an NGINX server that has SSL and also does client verification. For some reason it's not working. If I try out the certificates between 2 spring boot applications, they work. So certificates are good. I have the following nginx config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        
        ssl_certificate D:/nginx/server.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key D:/nginx/server.pkcs8;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        
        ssl_client_certificate D:/nginx/client.cer;
        ssl_verify_client on;

        
        server_name localhost;
        
        location /api/user {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/api/user ;
        }
        
        location /api/key {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/api/key ;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change this `ssl_verify_client on;` to `ssl_verify_client off;` I get the result I expect. So the rest of the configurations should be fine... I started NGINX today, would like to get some help.

Certificates are created by me. No issuer, no certificate chain. Self signed certificates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using certs signed by a public CA? If not, is nginx aware of the signing roots for the certs? You can add trusted CA certs via `ssl_trusted_certificate` if you aren't using a CA that would be in the typical shipped trusted CA list.

Comment: Certificates are created by me. Self signed certificates.

Comment: You'll want to use `ssl_trusted_certificate` to provide your self-signing root certificate, then.

Comment: Even tho if I add `ssl_trusted_certificate D:/nginx/client.cer;` to the config file, same. Does not work.